# Can't add more than 10 entries in bibliography - class webofc

Tags: bibliographies, document-classes

I am writing a scientific paper using the `webofc` document class which can be found [here](ftp://ftp.edpsciences.org/pub/web-conf/).

To insert my refences I use the `thebibliography environment`. The sample code is the following

```
\begin{thebibliography}{}
%
% and use \bibitem to create references.
%
\bibitem{G4Forum} \href{https://www.gen-4.org/gif/jcms/c_9260/public}{Generation-IV International Forum}
\bibitem{IFNEC}   \href{https://www.ifnec.org/ifnec/}{Intl. Framework for Nucl. Energy Cooperation (IFNEC)}
\bibitem{NEA}     \href{https://www.oecd-nea.org/}{Nuclear Energy Agency}
\bibitem{HPRL}    \href{https://www.oecd-nea.org/dbdata/hprl/hprl.pl}{High Priority Request List}
\bibitem{NEMEA}   \href{http://publications.jrc.ec.europa.eu/repository/handle/JRC42917}{M. Salvatores et al, NEMEA-4 proceedings, JRC42917}
\bibitem{ANDREA}  REFERENCE TO ANDREA's MEASUREMENT
\bibitem{NTOF-1}  \href{http://cds.cern.ch/record/601511/files/intc-2002-037.pdf?version=1}{U. Abbondanno et al., CERN-SL-2002-053 ECT}
\bibitem{NTOF-2}  \href{http://link.springer.com/article/10.1140%2Fepja%2Fi2013-13027-6}{C. Guerrero et al., Eur. Phys. J. A \textbf{49}, p. 1-15 (2013)}
\bibitem{NTOF-3}  \href{http://cds.cern.ch/record/1514680/files/n_TOF-PUB-2013-001.pdf?version=2}{E. Berthoumieux et al., CERN-nTOF-PUB-2013-001}
\bibitem{EAR2}    \href{http://www.sciencedirect.com/science/article/pii/S0168900215008566}{C. Weiß et al., NIMA \textbf{799}, p. 90-98 (2015)}
\bibitem{PS}      \href{https://irradiation.web.cern.ch/irradiation/Paper/cern2011-004.pdf}{J.P. Burnet et al., CERN-2011-004, 2011}
%
%\bibitem{RefJ}
% Format for Journal Reference
%Journal Author, Journal \textbf{Volume}, page numbers (year)
% Format for books
%\bibitem{RefB}
%Book Author, \textit{Book title} (Publisher, place, year) page numbers
% etc
\end{thebibliography}
```

to be inserted into file `template.tex` from class `webofc`.

The problem is when I insert the 11th `bibitem` when I get the following error

> ```
> pdfTeX error (ext4): \pdfendlink ended up in different nesting level than \pdfstartlink.
>
> \AtBegShi@Output ...ipout \box \AtBeginShipoutBox 
>                                                   \fi \fi 
> l.386 \end{document}
> ```

Any idea on why this is happening?

Note that, probably irrelevant, I am using ShareLaTeX to run my code.

Comment: thanks to the nicely color-highlighted image on my screen, i can see that there is a problem with `\bibitem{NTOF-2}` -- there is a percent sign in the middle of the url, which causes the rest of the line to be ignored..  i'm not sure how to fix that, nor if it is indeed causing premature termination of your bibliography, but it needs to be fixed.  try commenting out that line and see if the "stops at 10" problem goes away.

Comment: @barbarabeeton  Thank you for your comment! I don't think it has to do with that, because the project was being compiled with that. The moment I add the next `bibitem` it started having these problems..

Answer (score 3):

Well,  at last it seems to be simply a missing call for package `hyperref` in your code, because command `\href` needs a called package `hyperref`.

Please see the following MWE (I changed the images `tiger` to `example-image-a` and `example-image-b` from package `MWE` you should have installed, but you must not call it in the code):

```
\documentclass{webofc}
\usepackage[varg]{txfonts}   % Web of Conferences font
\usepackage{hyperref}  % <============================================== missing for \href
%
% Put here some packages required or/and some personnal commands
%
%
\begin{document}
%
\title{Insert your title here}
%
% subtitle is optionnal
%
%%%\subtitle{Do you have a subtitle?\\ If so, write it here}

\author{\firstname{First author} \lastname{First author}\inst{1,3}\fnsep\thanks{\email{Mail address for first
    author}} \and
        \firstname{Second author} \lastname{Second author}\inst{2}\fnsep\thanks{\email{Mail address for second
             author if necessary}} \and
        \firstname{Third author} \lastname{Third author}\inst{3}\fnsep\thanks{\email{Mail address for last
             author if necessary}}
        % etc.
}

\institute{Insert the first address here 
\and
           the second here 
\and
           Last address
          }

\abstract{%
  Insert your english abstract here.
}
%
\maketitle
%
\section{Introduction}
\label{intro}
Your text comes here. Separate text sections with
\section{Section title}
\label{sec-1}
For bibliography use \cite{RefJ}
\subsection{Subsection title}
\label{sec-2}
Don't forget to give each section, subsection, subsubsection, and
paragraph a unique label (see Sect.~\ref{sec-1}).

For one-column wide figures use syntax of figure~\ref{fig-1}
\begin{figure}[h]
% Use the relevant command for your figure-insertion program
% to insert the figure file.
\centering
\includegraphics[width=1cm,clip]{example-image-a}
\caption{Please write your figure caption here}
\label{fig-1}       % Give a unique label
\end{figure}

For two-column wide figures use syntax of figure~\ref{fig-2}
\begin{figure*}
\centering
% Use the relevant command for your figure-insertion program
% to insert the figure file. See example above.
% If not, use
\vspace*{5cm}       % Give the correct figure height in cm
\caption{Please write your figure caption here}
\label{fig-2}       % Give a unique label
\end{figure*}

For figure with sidecaption legend use syntax of figure
\begin{figure}
% Use the relevant command for your figure-insertion program
% to insert the figure file.
\centering
\sidecaption
\includegraphics[width=5cm,clip]{example-image-b}
\caption{Please write your figure caption here}
\label{fig-3}       % Give a unique label
\end{figure}

For tables use syntax in table~\ref{tab-1}.
\begin{table}
\centering
\caption{Please write your table caption here}
\label{tab-1}       % Give a unique label
% For LaTeX tables you can use
\begin{tabular}{lll}
\hline
first & second & third  \\\hline
number & number & number \\
number & number & number \\\hline
\end{tabular}
% Or use
\vspace*{5cm}  % with the correct table height
\end{table}
%
% BibTeX or Biber users please use (the style is already called in the class, ensure that the "woc.bst" style is in your local directory)
% \bibliography{name or your bibliography database}
%
% Non-BibTeX users please use
%
\begin{thebibliography}{}
%
% and use \bibitem to create references.
%
\bibitem{G4Forum} \href{https://www.gen-4.org/gif/jcms/c_9260/public}{Generation-IV International Forum}
\bibitem{IFNEC}   \href{https://www.ifnec.org/ifnec/}{Intl. Framework for Nucl. Energy Cooperation (IFNEC)}
\bibitem{NEA}     \href{https://www.oecd-nea.org/}{Nuclear Energy Agency}
\bibitem{HPRL}    \href{https://www.oecd-nea.org/dbdata/hprl/hprl.pl}{High Priority Request List}
\bibitem{NEMEA}   \href{http://publications.jrc.ec.europa.eu/repository/handle/JRC42917}{M. Salvatores et al, NEMEA-4 proceedings, JRC42917}
\bibitem{ANDREA}  REFERENCE TO ANDREA's MEASUREMENT
\bibitem{NTOF-1}  \href{http://cds.cern.ch/record/601511/files/intc-2002-037.pdf?version=1}{U. Abbondanno et al., CERN-SL-2002-053 ECT}
\bibitem{NTOF-2}  \href{http://link.springer.com/article/10.1140%2Fepja%2Fi2013-13027-6}{C. Guerrero et al., Eur. Phys. J. A \textbf{49}, p. 1-15 (2013)}
\bibitem{NTOF-3}  \href{http://cds.cern.ch/record/1514680/files/n_TOF-PUB-2013-001.pdf?version=2}{E. Berthoumieux et al., CERN-nTOF-PUB-2013-001}
\bibitem{EAR2}    \href{http://www.sciencedirect.com/science/article/pii/S0168900215008566}{C. Weiß et al., NIMA \textbf{799}, p. 90-98 (2015)}
\bibitem{PS}      \href{https://irradiation.web.cern.ch/irradiation/Paper/cern2011-004.pdf}{J.P. Burnet et al., CERN-2011-004, 2011}
%
\bibitem{RefJ}
% Format for Journal Reference
Journal Author, Journal \textbf{Volume}, page numbers (year)
% Format for books
\bibitem{RefB}
Book Author, \textit{Book title} (Publisher, place, year) page numbers
% etc
\end{thebibliography}

\end{document}
```

and the result (only page 3: bibliography:

[image: page 3: bibliography]

Comment: @Thanos I'm not sure that hyperlinks survive the merge process of all papers... and even if they do, they will not be visible in a print. So make sure you show the URLs explicitly.